# change unzipped folder name

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

I have a fairly large number of directories (500+), each directory (and possible sub-directories) contains 4 or more zip files.
I managed to piece together a bash script that unzips the compressed files while maintaining zip filename as directory and all the directory hierarchy.

For example: If I have a zip file called `100011_test123.zip`, and it contains 10 files. The script will uncompress all the files into `100011_test123/` directory.
The occurrence of numbers `100010` before the underscore in the filename/directoryname is totally random.

Here's the actual bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <directory-with-large-number-of-zip-files>
find . -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do unar -d -o "`dirname "$filename"`" "$filename"; done;
find . -name "*.zip" -type f -delete
```

Now I would like to update the script in order to remove the `100010_` from the .zip filename without tampering with the directory structure/hierarchy (I guess there's a way to rename the zip files before using `unar` command) and then uncompress the files into a directory without `100010_` at the beginning.

I have been stuck with this for more than 3 days. Any insights on this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some sample of your zip file names to figure where is that 100010_ within the zip name and within the unzipped folder, or are these to be unzipped in own folder you have to create, or is that 100010_ folder name part of the archive content? Do you have a reason to use unrar for zip files rather than unzip? Are there zip files in sub-folders you need to search or are these all in the same hierarchy level?

Comment: Hi Léa Gris,

Thank you for the script. It works like a charm.

Yes, the zip files are inside sub-directories.

And no, there's no reason to use Unrar inroder to unzip files.

Comment: Please follow this URL for directory hierarchy (all the sensitive infomation have been removed for obvious reasons):
[link](https://pasteboard.co/K1eSXXM.png)

I have a directory named ```uncompressed```. It contains 500+ sub-directories. Each of the 500+ sub-directory contains multiple zip files (some sub-directories are empty).
Is it possible to execute the script from ```uncompressed``` directory such that the files would unzip inside their respective sub-directories without the ```xxxxxx``` digits in the directory name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With all zip files at the same level, you don't need find, but a regular filename pattern globbing will do to iterate each zip archive.

And with bash's `globstar` option, you can also find the zip archives inside sub-directories

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob # Prevents iterating if no filename match

shopt -s globstar # ./**/ Allow searching inside sub-directories

# Set the basedir if you want all output directories at same place
#basedir="$PWD"

for zipfile in ./**/*.zip; do
  # Extract the base directory containing the archive
  zipdir="${zipfile%/*}"

  # Extract the base name without the directory path
  basename="${zipfile##*/}"

  # Remove the .zip extension
  # 100011_test123.zip -> 100011_test123
  extensionless="${basename%.zip}"

  # Remove everything before and first underscore 100011_
  # 100011_test123 -> test123
  outputdir="${basedir:-$zipdir}/${extensionless#*_}"

  # Create output directory or continue with next archive
  # mkdir -p test123
  mkdir -p "$outputdir" || continue

  # Unzip the zipfile into the outputdir and remove the zipfile if successful
  # unrar -d -o test123 100011_test123.zip && rm -f -- 100011_test123.zip
  unar -d -o "$outputdir" "$zipfile" && rm -f -- "$zipfile"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse directory name and filename first for each entry. Please check the `${fullpath%/*}` and `${fullpath##*/}` for this purpose. And **awk** for splitting filename with '_' and getting second part of it.

You can try following code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# cd directory
zip_files=($(find . -name "*.zip"))
for fullpath in "${zip_files[@]}"; do
    echo "Processing: "$fullpath""
    DIRNAME="${fullpath%/*}"
    FILENAME="${fullpath##*/}"
    NEW_FILENAME="`echo $FILENAME | awk -F'_' '{print $NF}'`"
    echo "  DIRNAME="$DIRNAME
    echo "  NEW_FILENAME="$NEW_FILENAME

    mv $fullpath "$DIRNAME/$NEW_FILENAME"
    # call unar command
    unar -d -o $DIRNAME $NEW_FILENAME
    # delete file if you want
done
```

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks for fixes.

Comment: `zip_files=($(find . -name "*.zip"))` This will again split file names with space or newline. To safely create an array from the output of a command, use `mapfile`:
`mapfile -d '' zipfiles < <(find . -name '*.zip' -print0)`